# Проблема с RegisterDeviceNotification

Tags: windows, c, service

Я пишу сервис Windows, который должен фиксировать в логе все подключаемые флешки. AFAIK, обыкновенные приложения получают `WM_DEVICECHANGE`, сервисам же надо подписываться с помощью `RegisterDeviceNotification`. Сообщения поступают в функцию диспетчеризации с кодом `SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT`.

Проблема: `RegisterDeviceNotification` проходит успешно, но сообщений почему-то не приходит.

[Исходник моего сервиса](http://pastebin.com/TJW7g6fN): он достаточно длинный и не всем интересный :)

**UPD.**

У меня неправильно написан фрагмент с регистрацией функции-обработчика. Надо:

```
hStatus = RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx( SERVICE_NAME, (LPHANDLER_FUNCTION_EX)ControlHandler, 0 );
```

А сигнатура функции такая:

```
DWORD ControlHandler(DWORD, DWORD, LPVOID, LPVOID);
```

Но это всё равно не работает :)

**UPD2.**
Обновил исходник, по прежнему не работает :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была не в коде, а в непраильно настроенном VirtualBox. Тему можно закрыть :)